# Issue with python understand API

Tags: python, database, operating-system

I am trying to run a python program that is developed by someone else. In that app, the understand API is used.
However, the app crashes and I have an issue with debugging since I am new to this technology.

The document for understand.open(dbname) shows that this error is caused by db is unreadable or does not exist.

the procedure of the code is basically like the following below:

```
self.udbFile = os.path.join(outputPath, "udbs", projName, self.sourceDirName + ".udb")
```

...

```
self._runCmd([UND_PATH, 'create', '-languages', 'Java', self.udbFile])
self._runCmd([UND_PATH, 'add', self.sourcePath, self.udbFile])
self._runCmd([UND_PATH, 'settings', '-metrics', 'all', self.udbFile]),
self._runCmd([UND_PATH, 'analyze', self.udbFile]),
```

...

```
db = understand.open(self.udbFile)
```

chunk #2 seems passed, and the error is thrown by #3

I tried to insert a print statement to see what self.udbFile is,
And The log in terminal is:

```
self.udbFile is: C:\Users\51676\Desktop\405\output\udbs\apache-nutch\.git.udb


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 54, in <module>
    main(config.items('main.projPaths'))
  File "main.py", line 30, in main
    app.extractSmells()
  File "C:\Users\51676\Desktop\405\src\app.py", line 56, in extractSmells
    db = understand.open(self.udbFile)
understand.UnderstandError: DBUnableOpen
```

Comment: Do you have the `.udb` file in your file system? To me, it looks like the path is wrong or the file doesn't exist.

Comment: I dont' think that .udb file exiseted initially. I think the code will create the .udb file while running, as self.udbFile = os.path.join(outputPath, "udbs", projName, self.sourceDirName + ".udb"), this statement is in __init__()

Comment: I don't know anything about the framework, but it is clear that your assumption is not correct from the error. Try to create at least an empty file, then run your code.